# why progress bar loading not showing actual data in fragment android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, exoplayer2.x

I am developing music app but when I run project only progressbar loading in my fragment not showing actual data
I want to know exactly where I am making mistake

below my HomeFragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    @Inject
    lateinit var songAdapter: SongAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        // inflate the layout and bind to the _binding
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[MainViewModel::class.java]
        setupRecyclerView()
        subscribeToObservers()

        songAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
            mainViewModel.playOrToggleSong(it)
        }
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() = binding.rvAllSongs.apply {
        adapter = songAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }

    private fun subscribeToObservers() {
        mainViewModel.mediaItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
            when(result.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    binding.allSongsProgressBar.isVisible = false
                    result.data?.let { songs ->
                        songAdapter.songs = songs
                    }
                }
                Status.ERROR -> Unit
                Status.LOADING -> binding.allSongsProgressBar.isVisible = true
            }
        }

    }

}
```

below my fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/allSongsProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvAllSongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivItemImage"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrimary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Playlist Title"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivItemImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSecondary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100 Songs"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivItemImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPrimary" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below my Songadapter class

```
class SongAdapter @Inject constructor(
    private val glide: RequestManager
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.SongViewHolder>() {

    //private lateinit var binding:ListItemBinding

    inner class SongViewHolder(val binding: ListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Song>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Song, newItem: Song): Boolean {
            return oldItem.mediaId == newItem.mediaId
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Song, newItem: Song): Boolean {
            return oldItem.hashCode() == newItem.hashCode()
        }
    }

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallback)

    var songs: List<Song>
    get() = differ.currentList
    set(value) = differ.submitList(value)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SongViewHolder {
       val binding =  ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return SongViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val song = songs[position]
        holder.binding.apply {
            tvPrimary.text = song.title
            tvSecondary.text = song.subtitle
            glide.load(song.imageUrl).into(ivItemImage)

            holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let { click ->
                    click(song)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Song) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Song) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return songs.size
    }
}
```

below my MainViewModel.kt class

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val musicServiceConnection: MusicServiceConnection
) : ViewModel() {
    
        private val _mediaItems = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Song>>>()
        val mediaItems: LiveData<Resource<List<Song>>> = _mediaItems
        val isConnected = musicServiceConnection.isConnected
        val networkError = musicServiceConnection.networkError
        val curPlayingSong = musicServiceConnection.curPlayingSong
        val playbackState = musicServiceConnection.playbackState
    
        init {
            _mediaItems.postValue(Resource.loading(null))
            musicServiceConnection.subscribe(
                MEDIA_ROOT_ID,
                object : MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback() {
                    override fun onChildrenLoaded(
                        parentId: String,
                        children: MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>
                    ) {
                        super.onChildrenLoaded(parentId, children)
                        val items = children.map {
                            Song(
                                it.mediaId!!,
                                it.description.title.toString(),
                                it.description.subtitle.toString(),
                                it.description.mediaUri.toString(),
                                it.description.iconUri.toString()
    
    
                            )
                        }
                        _mediaItems.postValue(Resource.success(items))
                    }
                })
    
    
        }
    
        fun skipToNextSong() {
            musicServiceConnection.transportControls.skipToNext()
        }
    
        fun skipToPreviousSong() {
            musicServiceConnection.transportControls.skipToPrevious()
        }
    
        fun seekTo(pos: Long) {
            musicServiceConnection.transportControls.seekTo(pos)
        }
    
        fun playOrToggleSong(mediaItem: Song, toggle: Boolean = false) {
            val isPrepared = playbackState.value?.isPrepared ?: false
            if (isPrepared && mediaItem.mediaId == curPlayingSong.value?.getString(METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID)) {
                playbackState.value?.let { playbackState ->
                    when {
                        playbackState.isPlaying -> if (toggle) musicServiceConnection.transportControls.pause()
                        playbackState.isPlayEnabled -> musicServiceConnection.transportControls.play()
                        else -> Unit
                    }
    
                }
            } else {
                musicServiceConnection.transportControls.playFromMediaId(mediaItem.mediaId, null)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCleared() {
            super.onCleared()
            musicServiceConnection.unsubscribe(
                MEDIA_ROOT_ID,
                object : MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback() {})
        }

}
```

Below MusicServiceConnection.kt

```
class MusicServiceConnection(
    context: Context
) {

    private val _isConnected = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>>()
    val isConnected: LiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>> = _isConnected
    private val _networkError = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>>()
    val networkError: LiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>> = _networkError
    private val _playbackState = MutableLiveData<PlaybackStateCompat?>()
    val playbackState: LiveData<PlaybackStateCompat?> = _playbackState
    private val _curPlayingSong = MutableLiveData<MediaMetadataCompat?>()
    val curPlayingSong: LiveData<MediaMetadataCompat?> = _curPlayingSong
    lateinit var mediaController: MediaControllerCompat

    private val mediaBrowserConnectionCallback = MediaBrowserConnectionCallback(context)
    private val mediaBrowser = MediaBrowserCompat(
        context,
        ComponentName(
            context,
            MusicService::class.java
        ),
        mediaBrowserConnectionCallback,
        null

    ).apply {
        connect()
    }
    val transportControls: MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls
        get() = mediaController.transportControls


    fun subscribe(parentId:String, callback: MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback){
        mediaBrowser.subscribe(parentId, callback)
    }

    fun unsubscribe(parentId:String, callback: MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback){
        mediaBrowser.unsubscribe(parentId, callback)
    }

    private inner class MediaBrowserConnectionCallback(
        private val context: Context
    ) : MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
        override fun onConnected() {
            mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, mediaBrowser.sessionToken).apply {
                registerCallback(MediaControllerCallback())
            }
            _isConnected.postValue(Event(Resource.success(true)))
        }

        override fun onConnectionSuspended() {
            _isConnected.postValue(
                Event(
                    Resource.error(
                        "The connection was suspended",
                        false
                    )
                )
            )
        }

        override fun onConnectionFailed() {
            _isConnected.postValue(
                Event(
                    Resource.error(
                        "Could connect media browser",
                        false
                    )
                )
            )
        }
    }

    private inner class MediaControllerCallback : MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: PlaybackStateCompat?) {
            _playbackState.postValue(state)
        }


        override fun onMetadataChanged(metadata: MediaMetadataCompat?) {
            _curPlayingSong.postValue(metadata)
        }

        override fun onSessionEvent(event: String?, extras: Bundle?) {
            super.onSessionEvent(event, extras)
            when (event) {

                NETWORK_ERROR -> _networkError.postValue(
                    Event(
                        Resource.error(
                            "Could not connect to the server. Please check your internet connection",
                            null
                        )
                    )
                )

            }
        }

        override fun onSessionDestroyed() {
            mediaBrowserConnectionCallback.onConnectionSuspended()
        }
    }

}
```

what I have tried I have done debugging it is not coming till on status== success and onerror it skipping success and onerror in debug mode it is only showing what is happening in onloading

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake and why data not showing

Comment: Have You debugged the application? I would make the program stop at the line at which You receive the `result` where the `status == SUCCESS`. Does the program even reach that code? If so, what is the data received? Maybe it is empty or null? Please, check it Yourself and update the question with relevant information :)

Comment: @sweak I have done debugging it is not coming till on status== success and onerror it skipping success and onerror in debug mode it is only showing what is happening in onloading

Comment: @sweak I have redited my question please check it

Comment: Does this line even get executed? `_mediaItems.postValue(Resource.success(items))`

Comment: yes it is executed @sweak

Comment: I think You're missing `songAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` after setting the `songs` to the adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247285/discussion-between-edgar-and-sweak).

Comment: @sweak I have used diffutils I dont have to setup songadapter.notifydatasetchanged maybe you can check my github repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in my musicservice in onloadchildren
previously it was written like this

```
override fun onLoadChildren(
        parentId: String,
        result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>
    ) {
        when (parentId) {
            MEDIA_ROOT_ID -> {
                val resultsSent = firebaseMusicSource.whenReady { isInitialized ->
                    if (isPlayerInitialized) {
                        result.sendResult(firebaseMusicSource.asMediaItems())
                        if (!isInitialized && firebaseMusicSource.songs.isNotEmpty()) {
                            preparePlayer(
                                firebaseMusicSource.songs,
                                firebaseMusicSource.songs[0],
                                false
                            )
                            isPlayerInitialized = true
                        }
                    } else {
                        mediaSession.sendSessionEvent(NETWORK_ERROR, null)
                        result.sendResult(null)

                    }

                }
                if (!resultsSent) {
                    result.detach()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

bt I changed inside if block like this
if (isInitialized) then it solved my problem